# Search Data from Array of object and inside object array of Object

Tags: javascript, react-native, search, arraylist, filter

In the below data array if a user is able to search with Fruits (**Category**) or Apple (**Subcategory**).

```
const data = [
  {
    "category": "Fruits",
    "subCategory": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "val": "Apple"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "val": "Banana"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "category": "Vagitable",
    "subCategory": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "val": "Tomato"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "val": "Potato"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**Output**: Search value "Fruits" or "Apple".

const data = [{
"category": "Fruits",
"subCategory": [
{
"id": 1,
"val": "Apple"
}
]
}]

Answer (score 0):

You search category and subCategory by find() array manipulation method.

```js
const data = [
  {
    "category": "Fruits",
    "subCategory": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "val": "Apple"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "val": "Banana"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "category": "Vagitable",
    "subCategory": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "val": "Tomato"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "val": "Potato"
      }
    ]
  }
]

const searchValue = "Tomato";

const output = data.find(items => 
  items.category === searchValue || 
  items.subCategory.some(subItem => subItem.val === searchValue)
);

console.log(output);
```

Comment: if I search with Vagitable then it works?

Comment: Yeah this work, that's why I take Vegitable example in the code

Answer (score 0):

- you need to use find method to achieve desired solution first we find
- in the main array and match with category if not find with category
- then check with subcategory

```js
const data = [
  {
    "category": "Fruits",
    "subCategory": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "val": "Apple"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "val": "Banana"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "category": "Vagitable",
    "subCategory": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "val": "Tomato"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "val": "Potato"
      }
    ]
  }
];
let input="Fruits";
let result = data.find(item => {
    if(item.category == input)
        return item;
    else{
       let ret=[];
       ret.push(item.subCategory.find(item2 => {
           return item2.val == input
        }))
        item.subCategory=ret;
        return item;
    }
});
console.log(result);
```